# Deriving Parallel and perpendicular vectors from triple vector product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

How would one go about resolving the vector $\vec{p}$ into parallel and perpendicular vectors to the given vector $\vec{w}$

By considering      -  $\vec{w}\times(\vec{p}\times\vec{w})$

So far I have used the triple vector product however I seem to just get zero when I do this so I feel like i'm making a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as $\vec p\times \vec w$ is perpendicular to both $\vec p$ and $\vec w$, we can decompose $\vec p$ as

$$\begin{align}
\vec p&=A\vec w+B[\vec w\times(\vec p\times \vec w)]\tag1
\end{align}$$

Note that $\vec w\times(\vec p\times \vec w)$ is perpendicular to $\vec w$.

---

Taking the inner product of $\vec p$ with $\vec w$, we find from $(1)$ that

$$A=\frac{\vec p\cdot \vec w}{|\vec w|^2} $$

---

Taking the vector product of $\vec p$ with $ \vec w$, we find from $(1)$ that

$$B=\frac{1}{|\vec w|^2}$$

---

Hence, denoting the unit vector along $\vec w$ as $\hat w=\frac{\vec w}{|\vec w|}$

$$\vec p=(\vec p\cdot \hat w)\hat w+ ( \hat w \times\vec p)\times \hat w$$

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you